# loopback mongo returning results for get but not for remote method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

```
myModel.remoteMethod('getName',
        {accepts: {arg: 'id', type: 'Number', required: true},
        http: {path: '/customer/:id', verb: 'get'},
        returns: {arg: 'results',type: 'Object'}
        });
myModel.getName = function(id, cb) {
  myModel.find({where:{"name id": id}},function(err,response){
  cb(null,response)
  });
 }
```

does not return any response for a remote.. can someone suggest where im making a mistake

a plain GET of all values gives me a result for ex:localhost:3000/api/getnames/

gives me: [name id: 1234,name:"abc"]

if i do localhost:3000/api/getnames/customer/1234 returns empty value

im using mongodb for fetching my backend values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `find` is an `array`.

But you define it in remote method as `object`.

Just change it like :

```
returns: {arg: 'results',type: 'array'}
```